# Is this sql query correct?

Tags: mysql, sql

Using table below 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wmg2C.png

How do i display the names of toys that processed by Female Employees who are in level 3, level 4, and level 5 (not level 1 or 2) and a list of all toys’ name with stores’ postcode 10005. **Write using union.**

```
SELECT Toy_name
FROM Toy T
INNER  JOIN hire_transaction H on T.toy_id = H.toy_id
INNER  JOIN Employee E on H.E_id = E.E_id
WHERE E_Sex = ‘F’
AND E_Level between ‘3’ and ‘5’
UNION
SELECT Toy_name, Store_id
FROM Toy T, Store S
WHERE T.Store_ID IN(
SELECT Store_ID
FROM STORE S
WHERE Store_Postcode = ‘10005’);
```

this is my attempt. am i correct?

Comment: Your query wont work,since when you combine queries with union/union all ,it must have same number of columns..remove store from select of union

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT Toy_name
FROM Toy T
INNER  JOIN hire_transaction H on T.toy_id = H.toy_id
INNER  JOIN Employee E on H.E_id = E.E_id
WHERE E_Sex = 'F'
AND E_Level between 3 and 5
UNION

SELECT Toy_name
FROM Toy T
WHERE T.Store_ID IN(
SELECT Store_ID
FROM STORE S
WHERE Store_Postcode = '10005');
```

When using `unions` the distinct selects must have the same number and types of columns.

Removed the unnecessary implicit `join` in your second query.

You used the wrong quotation marks, inserted the single quotes.

Comment: thanks didnt know about union requirements for usage

Comment: So does the query now deliver the correct result? :) Then please mark the answer as accepted. Also for your next question, thinks will be easier if you directly give information if there are error messages, how your table structure looks, what result you are expecting and what result you are getting instead.